# SwiftUI - Open external app with URL also goes back to home page

Tags: swiftui

I create 2 screens using SwiftUI. Main screen navigates to sub screen using NavigationLink. On the sub screen, There is a button which will trigger following code when user click it. It aims to navigate to email app with given email address.

The email app is opened successfully, but my app also automatically goes back to home screen. Is this special behaviour of NavigationView? is there any way to prevent this ?

```
let email = "abc@gmail.com"
let link = "mailto:\(email)"  
guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }
UIApplication.shared.open(url)
```

---

---

*UPDATE:*
After diving into the code, I found the root cause around the MyApp struct, which it always creates new instance of `ContentView` and inject new instance of `UserSettings`. I debugged with break-points and saw that when the app navigates to Email/Phone app, Myapp is called with updated `scenePhase` (.inactive or .background).
Then inside ContentView, it automatically fetches data and renders the main UI.

My new question is: Could we force it always use same instance of `ContentView` while the app moves to background and comes back?

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().environmentObject(UserSettings())
        }.onChange(of: scenePhase) { (newScenePhase) in
            switch newScenePhase{
            case .active:
                print("scene is now active!")
            case .inactive:
                print("scene is now inactive!")
            case .background:
                print("scene is now in the background!")
            @unknown default:
                print("Apple must have added something new!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the code of view and subview? Or minimal reproducible code?

Comment: Do you have any specific code to handle open URL in your application? Maybe the reason is there.

Comment: Thanks for your replies @RajaKishan . Please have a look my updated question after debugging.